# Calculating area with python qgis

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am a little stumped with determining the area of polygons in the python console. I want the output to be in meters^2, so using:

`qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setMapUnits(0)`

`qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()`

`cLayer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()`

`for f in cLayer.getFeatures(): print f["ID"], f.geometry().area()`

I get the the output of:

`1 0.000114895410903
2 0.00014639997019...`  - which suggests to me that the map units are still in in decimal degrees and not meters squared like I expected.

with some background reading, I then specified a localised CRS:

`wkt = 'PROJCS["SACRS_NO_27",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["unknown",SPHEROID["WGS84",6378137,298.257223563],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",27],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]'`
 and applied it with:

`coo = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(wkt)` and
`cLayer.setCrs(coo)`

I can check the mapUnits of cLayer with
`print cLayer.crs().mapUnits()` and this gives me '0' for metres.

Yet `for f in cLayer.getFeatures(): print f["ID"], f.geometry().area()` still gives me the same output as before, as if the units are still in decimal degrees.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What crs is your layer in?

Comment: EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - same as the project

Comment: And that is the reason.  You will need to enable on the fly projection and project it into a meters based projection in order to get that information back.

Comment: Okay - that works entering it manually. Do you have any ideas how to implement that within the console?